# Insert all missing rows into data table for a range of values for 2 columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am interested in inserting all missing rows into a data table for a *new* range of values for 2 columns.

Example, `dt1[,a]` has some values from 1 to 5, as does `dt1[,b]`, but i'd like not only all pair wise combinations to be present in columns a and b, but all combinations to be present in a newly defined range, e.g. 1 to 7 instead.

```
# Example data.table
dt1 <- data.table(a=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5),
b=c(1,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5),
c=sample(1:10,19,replace=T))

setkey(dt1,a,b)

# CJ in data.table will create all rows to ensure all
# pair wise combinations are present (using the nominated columns). 
dt1[CJ(a,b,unique=T)]
```

The above is great but will only use the max and min in the nominated columns. I'd like the inserted rows to give me all combinations between a new, nominated range, e.g. 1 to 7. There would be 49 rows.

```
# the following is a temporary workaround
template <- data.table(a1=rep(1:7,each=7),b1=rep(1:7,7))
setkey(template,a1,b1)

full <- dt1[template]
```

Comment: What about `dt1[CJ(a = 1:7, b, unique = TRUE)]`

Comment: i did not know you could do that, thanks a lot. In my case i would also set `b = 1:7`. If you add as an answer i can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the already existing values in 'a' column, we can have a range of values to pass into 'CJ' for the 'a'

```
dt1[CJ(a = 1:7, b, unique = TRUE)]
```

Comment: lovely, `data.table` is so straightforward sometimes. edit: of course, you're cross joining a new table, but where i nominated the "new" table as existing columns, i just needed to stipulate new columns completely.